# Was smoking allowed aboard hydrogen-filled zeppelins?

Tags: 20th-century, nazi-germany, germany, aircraft, transportation

The question is self explanatory:  Were passengers aboard rigid airships filled with hydrogen, like the Hindenburg, allowed to smoke?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check, but one would imagine so. It wasn't the passenger compartment that was full of hydrogen.

Comment: @T.E.D. - I was thinking more about the whole "If a fire breaks out we'll plummet from the sky like a stone, but at least we'll probably blow up before we hit the ground" aspect.  :)

Comment: @T.E.D. - It would appear from the answer that the ship's designers shared my concerns about the dangers presented by smoking aboard the Hindenburg.  Who knew?

Comment: Typing two words "smoking, dirigible" on the Google gives you immediate answer.

Comment: Do some preliminary research about the Hindenberg; hydrogen is not explosive and the speed and ferocity of the flames that consumed the Hindenberg had more to do with a chemical that had been sprayed on the skin of the gasbag to resist weather.

Comment: Watching the movie of the Hindenburg disaster, it looks like the hydrogen is being set on fire. The airship is raised due to the hot, combusting gas.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Smoking was allowed on the hydrogen filled zeppelin, the Hindenburg, but only in a specially made pressurized [smoking room](http://www.airships.net/hindenburg-smoking-room).

> the smoking room was separated from the rest of the passenger section by a double-door airlock.
>
> The smoking room was closely monitored at all times by a member of the zeppelin’s staff, and only one electric lighter was provided; no matches, lighters, or other open flames were allowed anywhere on the airship

Comment: That was quick.  Excellent answer, and thank you.

Comment: Interesting they should take such precautions, when the engines were sparked (e.g. dual-fuel gasoline/gas burners on the LZ 127 Graf Zeppelin).